# Why use kein instead of nicht in this answer?

Tags: difference

Q : Haben sie Geld?

A : Nein, sie haben kein Geld = They have NO MONEY (Translation from lingodeer : they don't have money)

I have an understanding that kein is used to imply they have no money whatsoever

Sie haben Geld nicht = They DON'T HAVE money

But I thought, wouldn't nicht also make sense? Because it implies they don't have money AT THE MOMENT right?

I am still a beginner, and I'm sorry if I misunderstood things! Thank you for anyone who could help!

Comment: Ah thank you! So I saw that Sie haben Geld nicht doesn't make sense. Does it sound unnatural? From what I understood, if there's an undefined noun in the sentence, then you automatically use kein to negate the noun? But if there's no noun, you have to use nicht to negate the verb? If both a verb and a noun is present, I do understand that kein emphasizes having no noun, while nicht emphasizes not doing a verb, but I'm still a bit confused if both emphasises sound pretty much the same... at least, in my mind ^^;

Comment: You could say *Sie haben das Geld nicht.* That would mean they don't have enough money to pay the price previously talked about, or they don't have the specific cash bills previously talked about.

Comment: Ahh, so nicht in that context means they DO have money, just not (enough) money they need to pay the bill?

Comment: @EekDeez: In "Sie haben das Geld nicht." "das Geld" means "that (amount of) money". Yes, it basically means they don't have enough, but if they have any money at all is not said. It *may* include them having no money at all.